# Changing odd and even numbers in a file to binary code

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to figure out how I would take all the odd numbers in a file and convert them to binary 1 and the even numbers in the file and change them to binary 0.  I am creating a binary search tree and I need to do the following for each element. 
- Decide if the element is even or odd, if even concatenate a 0 to my string, if odd concatenate a 1. 
-This will then build a binary String that represents a LONG
-Then I want to convert the binary string to a long using these;

```
new BigInteger {myString}
longValue();
```

Heres an example of the file:

```
1973
3522
3465
1825
701
4842
2457
2895
746
4367
```

This is what Ive got so far.
To find the odd  and then the even #'s

```
public void convert (TreeNode<E> node){
    for(int i = 1; i <= size(); i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){

        }
    }
    for(int i = 2; i <= size(); i++){
        if (i % 2 != 0){

        }
    }
}
```

So how would I convert the numbers to binary code and how would I convert the binary string  to a long. Please anything will help Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of what its supposed to do?  As it stands, its a bit unclear about what input you are getting and the intended output

Comment: Could you also please post what the input file will look like? While reading your description I had a vague understanding of what you want to do but based on the sample code you presented it seems my intuition may be mistaken.

Comment: new BigInteger("1000").longValue(); and 
Long.valueOf("1000"); are equivalent. To get their binary values try something like -     System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString((long) 1234)); - Also, you're binary string (in your example) seems to be a TreeNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a string ?

```
public void convert (TreeNode<E> node){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 1; i <= size(); i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            builder.append("0");
        }
    }
    for(int i = 2; i <= size(); i++){
        if (i % 2 != 0){
            builder.append("1");
        }
    }
    String myBinaryString = builder.toString();
}
```

But why do you make two different loops ? And why the second one starts at 2 ? Is that normal you don't use node parameter ?

You could do this :

```
public void convert (TreeNode<E> node){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 1; i <= size(); i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            builder.append("0");
        }
        else{
            builder.append("1");
        }
    }
    String myBinaryString = builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I was just building the string from what the OP said, he can do whatever he wants with the generated string after. And I don't know what size() method is, I reused the OP code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch size() is how big the file is